# live browser in Windows lock screen

Tags: windows

We are looking for a solution to run Windows programs - mainly browsers - on Windows (10) in screen lock mode. Means the browser should be visible and content should be live but nobody should be able to do any click or keyboard input without logging in by Ctrl-Alt-Del or something else.
It shouldn't be the typical kiosk mode because absolutely no interaction should be possible until loggin in. But everybody should see the live (monitoring) content on the screen.

Comment: Have you tried approaching Microsoft with a Design Change Request for this?

Comment: no, before this I would like to know if there is an existing solution I maybe don't know.

Comment: Apps can request lock screen *presence*, but there is no built-in way to hijack the entire lock screen, so far as I know.